# how to check in a loop for a folder or a file in php

Tags: php, loops, copy

For copying a folder and a file in php i use this loop:

```
if(is_dir($_POST['copyfile'])) {
    $copyfolder = recurse_copy($src_folder,$dest_folder);
    if( $copyfolder) {
    echo 'succeed-folder';
    exit;
    }
    else {
        echo 'failed-folder';

    exit;
    }
}
else {
    $copy = copy( $src_file_url, $dest_file );
    if($copy) {
    echo 'succeed-file';
    exit;
    }
    else {
        echo 'failed-file';

    exit;
    }
}
```

When copying a folder instead of a file, i check it with: `if(is_dir($_POST['copyfile']))`

In the case that it is really a folder, it copies the files in the folder correctly but gives me this echo: `failed-folder`

So there must be something wrong with the loop. What is wrong with the loop? I only want to distinguish if a `folder` or a `file` was copied with an echo

This is the function:

```
function recurse_copy($src_folder,$dest_folder ) {
    $copydir = opendir($src_folder);

    while(false !== ( $folder = readdir($copydir)) ) {
        if (( $folder != '.' ) && ( $folder != '..' )) {
            if ( is_dir($src_folder . '/' . $folder) ) {
                recurse_copy($src_folder. '/' . $folder,$dest_folder . '/' . $folder);
            }
            else {
                copy($src_folder. '/' . $folder , $dest_folder . '/' . $folder);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($copydir);
}
```

Comment: `recurse_copy` isn't standard PHP; are you using the user-comment example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php?

Comment: i agree, `recurse_copy` is a function. but thats not the problem. The problem is the echo in the loop

Comment: If your using [this code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#91010) then it never returns anything. So testing true/false will always be false.

Comment: @Nigel Ren ; yes it is that code. But in only want to give an correct echo if it succeeded. So how can i distinguish if a folder or a file was copied? Thats the main question

Comment: You will have to amend `recurse_copy()` to work out if it succeeds or fails and return something to flag this.

Comment: The problem is that all depends on the return value of `recurse_copy`. So we need that code instead of the given one.

Comment: post updated with code function

Comment: There is no `return` statement at all. Return `true` at the end, `false` if `copy` returns `false`. Also check `recurse_copy` in the `if` branch.

Comment: Please note my update. NigelRen was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a `return` statement at all. Therefore the function returns "void" which is evaluated to `false`. You need to return a bool value indicating if an error occurred.

This version does not stop the copy process, it just tracks if all operations were successful:

```
function recurse_copy($src_folder,$dest_folder ) {
  $success = true;
  $copydir = opendir($src_folder);
  if(!$copydir)
    return false;

  while(false !== ( $folder = readdir($copydir)) ) {
    if (( $folder != '.' ) && ( $folder != '..' )) {
      if ( is_dir($src_folder . '/' . $folder) ) {
        $success = recurse_copy($src_folder. '/' . $folder,$dest_folder . '/' . $folder) && $success;
      }
      else {
        $success = copy($src_folder. '/' . $folder , $dest_folder . '/' . $folder) && $success;
      }
    }
  }
  closedir($copydir);

  return $success;
}
```

Comment: You say it won't stop the copy process but using `$success = $success &&` will stop the copy happening as soon as any option fails, but the loop will carry on and not do anything.

Comment: @NigelRen Oh yes, of course! Thank you! Updated the code flipping action and `$success`

Comment: As NigelRen remarked, due to optimization the code after `false && ` would never be called. The variable has to come after the command.

Answer (score 0):

An example of how you could alter the `recurse_copy()` function is to test each point which can be a problem - `opendir()`, `mkdir()` and `copy()` and they return false if any step fails.  So this value is checked to stop the loop on failure and then returned at the end...

```
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) {
    $dir = opendir($src);
    // As long as opendir is OK, then mkdir, or set failure
    $success = ($dir)?mkdir($dst):false;
    while($success && (false !== ( $file = readdir($dir))) ) {
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) {
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) {
                $success = recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
            }
            else {
                $success = copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
    }
    if ( $dir )    {
        closedir($dir);
    }

    return $success;
}
```